# Android app - toodledo v3 api - adding a folder (using a POST request)

Tags: android

Getting connected from an Android app to Toodledo API v3 works. 
So, I know that I have a valid access_token (and refresh token).
GET requests work.

How can I add a folder ... using a POST request?

The code is below ... it keeps on spinning for new access tokens.

```
HttpResponse response = null;
JSONObject folderJS;
try { 
    Credential cred = flow.loadCredential( userId);
    String apiCallUrl = "https://api.toodledo.com/3/folders/add.php";

    GenericData data = new GenericData();
    data.put( "name", folderName);
    data.put( "private", "1");
    // data.put( "access_token", accessToken); <== this is wrong

    JsonHttpContent httpContent = new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), data);
    response = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory( cred).buildPostRequest( 
                     new GenericUrl( apiCallUrl), httpContent).execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

data.put( "access_token", accessToken);

When you add this line you get errors in processing the request. So, user error.